# Using GPS with CLLocationManager, some issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gps, cllocationmanager

I would like to speak with you about the iPhone coreLocation. Reading around I messed up, much more than I knew it before and I came up with questions about it.

I start with you that I have done some testing around my city but with poor results, often receiving as parameter -1 to `newLocation.course` and `newLocation.speed` having "5" as `newLocation.horizontalAccuracy`.

**1)** specifying that the measurements shall be measured mainly in the background, as do many other apps taking the journey, such as walking, what and how should I go to set the parameters of my CLLocationManager?

here is the code:

```
   locationM = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   [locationM setDelegate:self];
   [locationM setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
   [locationM setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
   [locationM startUpdatingLocation];
```

**2)** I thought that the precise way to keep track of distance traveled, speed and altitude  is to call the delegate of CLLocation every few seconds with an NSTimer going to call a method that contains `[locationM startUpdatingLocation]`. you think is the right way to get?

**3)** How do I extract a good result for the speed? I had thought that every time I get a newLocation the comparison with the previous one and through a calculation that extrapolates the speed has been reached from point A to point B, for example with `[newLocation distanceFromLocation: oldLocation]`. Or if you set the speed property asset returns good results?

you have any idea or trick to make the app work well?

briefly repeat the features, must obtain the speed in km / h based on movements like running, cycling ... tracing the route on average precisely without damaging the battery and  work strictly in the background

I believe that a comprehensive response could become a guide for many newcomers to the head of GPS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I track the speed and distance traveled in the background using the iPhone's GPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175839/how-can-i-track-the-speed-and-distance-traveled-in-the-background-using-the-ipho)

Answer (score 0):

You are close. I would use your filter to sort out your location updates. Make sure they are accurate enough for you. there should be one for headings, use that one. Then just accept the location updates in your -didUpdateToLocation method. I believe that gets location updates every second while -startUpdatingLocation is running. No need for a timer or anything flashy.

Your remaining questions are just math problems. Calculating distance traveled and time. I can't help you in that regard. But there are plenty of other answers out there that should get you what you need.